# Phalcon: How do I forward during beforeException when the exception is raised before dispatching?

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying to rescue an exception that occurs before anything is dispatched, and forward that error to an error controller that would display a nice error page. The problem is that `forward()` is doing nothing is this case, the error controller is not invoked.

The following code is a sample of the events attached to the dispatcher instance:

```
    $eventsManager->attach('dispatch:beforeDispatchLoop', function($event, $dispatcher) {
        throw new Exception('Just because.');
    });

    $eventsManager->attach("dispatch:beforeException", function($event, $dispatcher, $exception) {

        $dispatcher->forward([
            'module' => 'frontend',
            'controller' => 'errors',
            'action' => 'show',
            'params' => [ 400 ]
        ]);

        …
    });
```

Note: I throw the exception *before* the dispatch loop, because this is where I have trouble forwarding. Forwarding works fine when the dispatcher has already invoked a controller's action.

The following is the stack strace of the exception:

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'Just because.' in /vagrant/application/config/services-web.php:27
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(Phalcon\Events\Event), Object(Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher), NULL)
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Events\Manager->fireQueue(Array, Object(Phalcon\Events\Event))
#2 [internal function]: Phalcon\Events\Manager->fire('dispatch:before...', Object(Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher))
#3 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#4 /vagrant/public/index.php(24): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#5 {main}
```

Do you know how I can fix that, or if there is a better way to solve this? The exception is raised by a service.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that [beforeDispatchLoop](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/dispatching.html#dispatch-loop-events) is before the dispatcher is even initialized. Try changing to beforeDispatch:

```
$eventsManager->attach('dispatch:beforeDispatch', function($event, $dispatcher) {
    throw new Exception('Just because.');
});
```

Furthermore this section in the docs might apply: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/dispatching.html#handling-not-found-exceptions

> Only exceptions produced by the dispatcher and exceptions produced in
>   the executed action are notified in the ‘beforeException’ events.
>   Exceptions produced in listeners or controller events are redirected
>   to the latest try/catch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer David, but I throw the exception _before_ the dispatch loop, because this is where I have trouble forwarding. Forwarding works fine when the dispatcher has already invoked a controller's action. Also this statement from the doc might not be accurate since the `dispatch:beforeException` is perfectly invoked in my example.